# Avoid query parameters duplication when generating a MAC for requests in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I am using gatling (2.1.7) in order to stress test an API.

For of all I have to request a transaction id and shared secret in order to authenticate all subsequent calls.

```
scenario("API").exec(http("authorize")
  .post("/api/v1/xxx/authorize")
  .formParam("client_key", "a_very_strong_key")
  .check(jsonPath("$.response.txId").saveAs("id"))
  .check(jsonPath("$.response.txSecret").saveAs("secret")))
```

All other calls must contain a query parameter `signature` which is a mac of the other request parameters.

I wrote this piece of code to do that

```
scenario("API").exec(http("call")
  .get("/api/v1/call")
  .queryParam("id", "${id}")
  .queryParam("param1", "aaaaaa")
  .queryParam("param2", "bbbbbb")      
  .queryParam("signature", session => sign(session, Map(
    "id" -> session("id").as[String],
    "param1" -> "aaaaaa",
    "param2" -> "bbbbbb"))))

/* ... */

def sign(session: Session, params: Map[String, String]) : String = {
    val str = canonicalize(params)
    format_mac(session("secret").as[String], str)
}
```

However I have to duplicate all query parameter names and values in the sign method call and it is clearly a bad practice. It is possible to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sign a request, so use a [SignatureCalculator](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_request.html?highlight=signaturecalculator#signature-calculator).

Comment: Thank you Stéphane. I had seen the doc but I took the sentence "You might want to generate some HMAC header based on other request information" too literally. I successfully updated my code to use `SignatureGenerator` and it is now working well.

Comment: Hey Jean-Christophe! Glad it helped. You're right that documentation needs some polishing there. I just pushed some. Cheers.